# Autocompletion for indexing?

Tags: indexing, editors, auto-completion

Is there any text editor or plugin that helps while indexing a LaTeX file, for example by suggesting the entries I have already used, when I write `index{` ?
(At the moment I use TexStudio on Windows)

Comment: What OS do you use? Text editor?

Comment: I think Overleaf has something similar, but it is online.